# Convert a vector into a list, each element in the vector as an element in the list

Tags: r, r-faq

The vector is like this:

```
c(1,2,3)
#[1] 1 2 3
```

I need something like this:

```
list(1,2,3)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 2
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 3
```

I tried this:

```
list(c(1,2,3))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 145):

Simple, just do this:

```
as.list(c(1,2,3))
```

Comment: FYI: It seems to ignore NULL values in `as.list(c(0, NULL,1))`.

Comment: @OlegMelnikov you can't pass `NULL` into a vector `c()`, you can pass `NA` if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 12):

An addition to the accepted answer: if you want to add a vector to other elements in a longer list, as.list() may not produce what you expect.  For example: you want to add 2 text elements and a vector of five numeric elements (1:5), to make a list that is 7 elements long.

```
L<-list("a","b",as.list(1:5))
```

Oops: it returns a list with 3 elements, and the third element has a sub-list of 5 elements; not what we wanted!  The solution is to join two separate lists:

```
L1<-list("a","b")
L2<-as.list(1:5)
L<-c(L1,L2) #7 elements, as expected
```